# C++ suspend a thread and reactivate via a different thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I haven't done much multi threading so I didn't know quite how to search for this question. It might have been answered already, I just didn't know what I was looking for specifically enough.

Basically I am hoping for a way to suspend a thread at a specific point in its execution. I then want to be able to resume the thread right after where it got suspended via a different thread.

Is there anything like that on windows?

Comment: Are you asking specifically for the Windows API? The current standard supports [multithreading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) very well in a portable manner already.

Comment: Would I be looking at using condition_variable to do what I'm thinking?

Comment: Yes, that was the 1st thing coming to my mind.

Comment: So from what I see, I need to have a mutex for each thread i want to suspend that is shared between the locked thread and the thread unlocking it. Is that it? That seems straightforward enough!

Answer (score 1):

Try using a std::condition_variable. Condition variables are 'synchronization primitives" that can be used to block threads. You can find more info on condition variables here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Below is an example of a quick C++ program that demonstrates the behavior in question. You can block and unblock a thread from another thread like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<mutex>
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex lock;
void foo(){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(lock);
        cv.wait(ulock);
        std::cout<<"Thread Complete"<<std::endl;
}
void bar(){
        cv.notify_all();
}
int main()
{
        std::thread first(foo);
        std::thread second(bar);
        first.join();
        second.join();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll try include that idea in my project and let you know how it went. Do you know if it's possible to assign a mutex to an element of a structure? I'm getting an error when trying to do that.

Comment: What do you mean "assign a mutex to an element of a structure" Do you mean like to include a mutex in a STL data structure?

Comment: I created a structure named threadInfo that consists of a mutex and an int. I want to keep a std::list of that structure.  When I try to do 
std::mutex newMutex;
threadInfo info;
info.m = newMutex;

I get the error, std::mutex operator = is a deleted function

Comment: That struct already created default mutex. You cant assign mutexes to other mutexes. In fact, you don't actually need to. The instance of your struct already has a mutex ready to go. Is there a reason you're trying to change that mutex, or are you just trying to make sure one exists?

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. It just went right over my head that the struct already had a mutex. For some reason I saw it like I only created a container for a mutex and still had to put one in. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is correct in spirit, but the code posted has many flaws, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait. The wait function is allowed to "spuriously" end. See the example code at the bottom of the page for a correct usage example.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but just doing

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<mutex>
std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex lock;
void foo() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(lock);
    cv.wait(ulock);
    std::cout << "Thread Complete" << std::endl;
}
void bar() {
    cv.notify_all();
}
int main()
{
    std::thread second(bar);
    std::thread first(foo);
    
    first.join();
    second.join();
    return 0;
}
```

so for example starting "second" as..ehr... first

this LOCKS in visual studio , for example..

(what I expect, as we notify BEFORE someone is waiting for the notification...)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29822122)